# Rails. a href=#page deactivates javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble to find the correct way to do this. In my landing page I got a inner link like this:

```
<a href="#destacados">Destacados</a>
```

When I click on it, the page go to the #destacados id, but all the javascript stop working, so the carrusel just dies. I'm not sure if this can help, but when I click the link, the address bar change to /myapp/#destacados ... may be it has trouble routing that...  any idea??
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you show how you are binding the click event to your `<a>` ?

Just tested with JQuery (could be without)

```
<a href='#destacados'>Go To Destacados Section</a>
<script>
  $(function () { 
     $("a[href='#destacados']").click( function () { console.log('clicked'); });
});
</script>
```

The focus goes to the anchor and `clicked` is printed